# Import monad state

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to import the monad State. 
I did the following command:

```
:m Control.Monad.State
```

But the module cannot be found. I'm using `GHCi, version 7.0.4:`.

Can you give me some hint to fix the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed the [mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing [the `mtl` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl).

You can either install it from Hackage yourself; or install [the Haskell Platform](http://haskell.org/platform), which comes with the necessary libraries.

Comment: Thank you, i installed the `libghc-mtl-dev` package from Debian Repositories. It works now.